# Woocommerce payment after owner updates shipping

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following (very stupid) scenario:
I am building an ecommerce website based on Woocommerce and my client insists (although i have even threatened to not take the assignment) that the users should place their order without shipping cost and without paying. Then he wants to manually update the shipping cost on their order and then the clients should proceed to the payment methods.
Obviously this will not be real time.
Obviously this is probably the worst UX ever. Nevertheless I would like to know if there is a way to actually do this with or without plugins as i have been unable to find a way to make it work like this.

Comment: You will need to ask in a WooCommerce-specific site as third-party plugins are off-topic here. It is probably possible, but the exact combination of add-ons and custom code needed is something you'll need to determine. However, your gut instinct here is probably the right way to go, as if the client is insistent upon poor UX in this case they may be insistent about other unwise coding decisions.